# Is it possible to make sure a hidden form element isn't edited?

Tags: javascript, forms, zend-form, zend-framework

I'm using Zend forms. I have a form to add a row to a database, which then generates a form with an 'Undo' button, along with a hidden element with the id of the added row. The 'Undo' form is posted with that just hidden element as the post data, but I'm wondering if there is a way to make sure that it wasn't modified, like with Javascript or something, so that only the most recently created row by that user can be deleted. Is that possible?

More details, if they are necessary: The constructor for the undo form takes the row id as a parameter, so I can't add an 'identical' validator because the only data I can check against is what was posted in the 'Undo' form, not the 'add' form. 
Also, I need a solution that doesn't depend on Javascript.

Edit: Looks like sessions is the way to go. Got it working.

Comment: If you need that kind of security, then don't pass the 'undo' data through the client side of things. Keep it in the session, and use ajax to retrieve clean copies each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your only choice is to validate the form on the back-end. Input from the user should not and cannot be trusted.

You could store the ID in the user's session and validate the input against that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.hash

Comment: That element is useful for detecting if the form was posted from somewhere else, but I don't see how it prevents hidden data from being modified. Also, while normally that kind of CSRF protection would be nice, I don't think that would work in this case, because the undo form is created from POST data, I would need to save the originally constructed form between posts for the isValid() function.

Comment: Based on http://www.zend.com//code/codex.php?ozid=626&single=1 , I wrote http://freebeer.smithii.com/www/_source.php?file=%2Fhome%2Fross%2Fpublic_html%2Ffreebeer%2Flib%2FHTML%2FLockFormFields.php . The demo is here: http://freebeer.smithii.com/www/demo/HTML.LockFormFields.php